# React and TypeScript, Object is possibly 'null'. TS2531

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React with TypeScript I have this error while building:

Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531

[image]

But I have this code:

```
if (usersNode && usersNode.getLinkedRecords('edges') != null)
usersNode.getLinkedRecords('edges').forEach((edge: any) => {
  const node = edge.getLinkedRecord('node')

  nodesMapping[node.getValue('usuarioId')] = node.getDataID()
})
```

Why? I'm saying explicitly that if that Object is not null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that the issue is that

```
usersNode.getLinkedRecords('edges')
```

is a function call.  Typescript can't "know" that it will return the same thing the second time you call it.

Try

```
const edges = usersNode && usersNode.getLinkedRecords('edges');
if (edges !== null)
    edges.forEach((edge: any) => {
        const node = edge.getLinkedRecord('node')
        nodesMapping[node.getValue('usuarioId')] = node.getDataID()
    })
```